# Context manager to assert no database queries are issued in a block

Tags: python, django

How can I write a context manager that, in test/dev, asserts that there are no database queries in its block? The goal here is to force usage of select_related/prefetch related, and make it an error to forget to do so. Eg, given these models:

```py
class SomeSingleThing(models.Model):
    somefield = models.IntegerField()
    someotherfield = models.CharField(max_length=42)

class SomeManyThing(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(SomeSingleThing)
```

This should raise an exception, because select_related is missing, and so a query gets performed inside the forbidden zone:

```py
obj = SomeSingleThing.objects.get(pk=1)
with forbid_queries():
    val = obj.parent.somefield
# => exception
```

And this should not, because we selected everything we needed:

```py
obj = SomeSingleThing.objects.select_related('parent').get(pk=1)
with forbid_queries():
    val = obj.parent.somefield
# no exception
```

Comment: Aha, here's a partial answer: this exists in django, but only as a test utility. I want to put it as an assertion in all serializers by default, so that doesn't quite help me, but it's a good starting point. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries

Comment: Looks like the code for assertNumQueries should be pretty easy to generalize into something I can use for this.